# which is the bes javascript library for text box with rich text editing options

Tags: javascript, textbox, richtextbox, text-editor

On my website I want to provide a text box that has basic text editing options.

- It should at least have the text editing options as that provided in stackoverflow text box but I need some more advanced features.
- I had a look at ckeditor,  and it does provide a lot of features, but it is a bit overdo. Moreover it is not easily customizable.

Can anybody suggest which is the best javascript library for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't know if it's the "best", but i recommend [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/).

Comment: Tiny has a large user base, is very customizable and well documented. I was able to satisfy almost all feature requests for a large project with just a few tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

YUI has a rich text control: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/

As for the SO Markdown editor, it's open source: http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/

Comment: YUI is a rich, well documented code library that is easy to extend. Best bet if you need a lot of custom features.